# Understanding Keras/Tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I encountered my problem while trying to make an neural network with karas on the ucf101 dataset. To get started I loaded the dataset using `tensorflow_datasets` like so:

```
(train, test) , info = tfds.load('ucf101', split = ['train', 'test'], shuffle_files = True, with_info = True)
print(info)
```

According to the info, the dataset has the following features:

```
    features=FeaturesDict({
        'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, num_classes=101),
        'video': Video(Image(shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)),
    }),
```

How can I input the data (that has 3 dimensions `shape=(256, 256, 3)`) into an RNN when the RNN layer expects "A 3D tensor, with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]." I can't seem to understand what timesteps and feature is for my dataset.

Here is the code I have to create my RNN and its resulting error:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(128, input_shape=(256,256,3), return_sequences = True))
model.summary()
```

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "simple_rnn_24" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 256, 256, 3)`

I tried to input the training data into the RNN. I was expecting the RNN layer to be able to work with a 3d input size.

Comment: The `SimpleRNN` layer takes a 3D input shape `(bach_size, timesteps, features)`. Your input shape is 4D: `(batch_size, 256, 256, 3)`

Comment: @AloneTogether how do I pass the 4d data into the RNN Layer?

Comment: You could pass it channel by channel for example.

Comment: @AloneTogether, could you elaborate? Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: I could but can you first explain why you want to use a RNN layer?

Comment: @AloneTogether yeah for sure! It’s more for my personal understanding, LSTM or CNN would be fine as well

Comment: It just does not make my sense if your data does not have a temporal (time) dimension.

Comment: @AloneTogether Because it is video data, the data is in the form [batch_size, frames, height, width, channels] where (hight, width and channels are 256, 256, 3). I suppose the time dimension is the number of frames

Comment: Hi @Maxwell, You could have used `Conv3D` layer for the video dataset. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/video/video_classification) for your reference. Thank you.